# iCheck and toggle DIV's (hide/show) don't work well together

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, icheck

I am using iCheck on our website, but I am experiencing issues when I want to use a toggle (hide/show) DIV for displaying additional information about a product.

I tried numerous things, but all without success. I created a short version of the problem I am experiencing. See below.

```
    jQuery('input').iCheck({
        inheritID: true,
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
        increaseArea: '20%'
    });

function updateConfigurableOptions(i, billingCycle) {

    jQuery.post("cart.php", 'a=cyclechange&ajax=1&i='+i+'&billingcycle='+billingCycle,
        function(data) {
            jQuery("#productConfigurableOptions").html(jQuery(data).find('#productConfigurableOptions').html());
            jQuery('input').iCheck({
                inheritID: true,
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
                increaseArea: '20%'
            });
        }
    );
    recalctotals();

}
```

And

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="http://neverlands.org/icheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://neverlands.org/icheck/icheck/square/blue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="product-configurable-options" id="productConfigurableOptions">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dont-target-this"></label>

                    <div class="webhostconfigopties">
                        <label for="dont-target-this">What kind of product do you want?</label>
                    </div><br>
                    <label class="" id="Product A - Normal / Standard product" name="Product A - Normal / Standard product">
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue">
                        <input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="configoption[5]" value="15" type="radio">
                        <ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>
                        Product A - Normal / Standard product
                    </label>
<br />
                    <label class="" id="Product B - Special order +2 weeks time" name="Product B - Special order +2 weeks time">
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue">
                        <input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="configoption[5]" value="14" type="radio">
                        <ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>
                        Product B - Special order +2 weeks time
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

<p><hr></p>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="dont-target-this"></label>

                    <div class="webhostconfigopties">
                        <label for="dont-target-this">Do you want something extra to it?</label>
                    </div><br>
                    <label class="" id="No, thank you. Nothing extra." name="No, thank you. Nothing extra.">
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue">
                        <input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="configoption[5]" value="15" type="radio">
                        <ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>
                        No, thank you. Nothing extra.
                    </label>
<br />
                    <label class="" id="Yes, I want one extra option." name="Yes, I want one extra option.">
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue">
                        <input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="configoption[5]" value="14" type="radio">
                        <ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>
                        Yes, I want one extra option.
                    </label>

<br />
                    <label class="" id="Yes, I want all possible extra options. This will take longer." name="Yes, I want all possible extra options. This will take longer.">
                        <div style="position: relative;" class="iradio_square-blue">
                        <input style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" name="configoption[5]" value="14" type="radio">
                        <ins style="position: absolute; top: -20%; left: -20%; display: block; width: 140%; height: 140%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins></div>
                        Yes, I want all possible extra options. This will take longer.
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>

                <p></p>

<div id="addinfo-product-a" style="font-size:32px;color:red;">
    Additional information in regards to product A
</div>

<div id="addinfo-product-b" style="font-size:32px;color:green;">
    Additional information in regards to product B
</div> 

<div id="addinfo-extraoption-b" style="font-size:32px;color:blue;">
    Additional information in regards to extra option 2
</div>

<div id="addinfo-extraoption-c" style="font-size:32px;color:brown;">
    Additional information in regards to extra option 3
</div>
```

The included JQuery is essential for iCheck, however I am starting to think that is also the cause of the problems. Maybe someone, who understand JQuery/JS can solve this problem?

The only thing I am trying to achieve is getting the corresponding DIV (with additional information about a product) being shown. I would prefer to use fadein / fadeout over toggle.

Anyways, I tried several things / solutions which were found on Google and on Stackoverflow. All of them work, ***EXCEPT*** when you use iCheck. I have no clue why that is. As soon as iCheck is in play, the DIV's won't show up (or go away).

Anyone knows a workaround to make a DIV show/hide in conjunction with iCheck.

I have a working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5hvmzjzf/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the `ifChecked` and `ifUnchecked` events on the input elements and do the toggling of the extra information elements in the callback functions.

```
$('input').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    var extraInformationId = $(this).closest('label').attr('data-extrainformationid');
    if(extraInformationId != undefined) {
        $('#' + extraInformationId).fadeIn(500);
    }
});
```

Please, see the updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5hvmzjzf/1/).

P.S. I have used *data-attributes* in the *label* element to hold the id of the extra information element

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is it possible to target label name or ID, instead of using "data-extrainformationid"...? Reason for this, is that I cannot manipulate "data-extrainformationid", as everything is generated by WHMCS.

Comment: I did try to use your solution btw, but instead of using "addinfo-product-a" for "data-extrainformationid", I used the variable from WHMCS, so it would read: data-extrainformationid="{$options.nameonly}". Where "{$options.nameonly}" would be any of the answers, for example: "Product A - Normal / Standard product", but that didn't work. You could hover the options, but it didn't select them when clicked?

Comment: you need to define some sort of logic, have the mapping stored in a javascript object, or based on the information you have, like id/name of the input element being checked/unchecked, get the id of the extra information element to toggle. For starters, there must be a relation between the input element and the extra information element like an id of the record or something, that can be made as `data-extrainformationid` of the label element and `id` of the extra information element

Comment: Hmmm... I know HTML and CSS, I know how to modify existing code (PHP, JS) to make it work for me in most cases, but what you described sounds like like abacadabra to me. Sorry :S If I use "Product A - Normal / Standard product" (or one of the other options) for "data-extrainformationid" it doesn't work. I can hover the choices (circle shows), but when I "click/select" it, it doesn't do anything (doesn't get checked status).

Comment: not aware of how WHMCS works, but like the field `{$options.nameonly}` you have mentioned, there must be a unique identifier, that can be used as the value for the `data-extrainformation` and id for the extra information div.

Comment: Well, thats why I used "{$options.nameonly}" it's already unique. Because no product option is used twice on a page?

Comment: okay, so i update the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hvmzjzf/3/), have used id as the selector for the additional information section, so the id which would be `{$options.nameonly}`, would also be used as the value for `data-extrainformationfor` attribute of the extra information div. Hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: Man...! You're the best! I don't understand what you did, yes I see what you have added, but I don't understand that this works now. Been busy with this for several days, nothing, nada worked. And the code you provided now absolutely works! I take a deep bow for you and your effort! Highly appreciate it! A+++++++++++